# How to check if JavaScript alert is present (or not present) in a Capybara session?

Tags: javascript, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm trying to write a test that confirms that no JavaScript alert is present on the page (because in capybara-webkit, it is silencing this alert, but in selenium it correctly raises an error). How can I write a test to `expect(page).to_not have_alert`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior will be changing in capybara-webkit 2.0 to follow the example set by Selenium.

In the mean time, you can check `page.driver.alert_messages` to make sure no alerts have been opened.

Comment: I notice that this method is deprecated. Do you know if there will be an alternative to this in the future? I think being able to programmatically access the last alert message is really useful.

Comment: The current plan is to fully remove these methods in capybara-webkit 2.0. We're trying to minimize the amount of behavior we implement that Capybara itself doesn't support.